# Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

> Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value'  how i access?

```
public function idcount($id)
{
     $stats = DB::table('questions')
     ->select( DB::raw("COUNT('id') as value"))
         ->where('user_id',$id)
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->get(
        );
        return $stats.value;
}
```

Comment: Change `value` to `$value`.

Comment: In PHP, you can't access object properties or methods with `dot` notation. Use `return $stats->value`

Comment: i change but i getting error  'Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::__toString() must not throw an exception'

Comment: #Erol i use return $stats->value but still error  **Property [value] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
return $stats[0]->value;
```

instead of

```
return $stats.value;
```

because you are using Query Builder and `get` method returns collection of results and you want to get `value` column from this collection

Comment: **Undefined offset: 0**